# Converting specific equations from Polar to Cartesian

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

These different equations are given in Polar and my goal is to plot them in Cartesian coordinate system:

1. $r = \cos(4φ)$
2. $ φ = \dfrac r {r-1}$, $r > 1$

I am aware of:

- $x = r \cos( φ )$
- $y = r \sin( φ )$
- $r^2 = x^2 + y^2\\$

However I cannot figure out how to use these traits properly, and I am not able to find any relatable examples.

Any hints how should I approach this?

Comment: Are 1. and 2. different cases?

Comment: I changed $r * cos( φ )$ to $r \cos( φ )$.  That is proper notation. $\qquad$

Comment: Yes, they are different cases.

Comment: Do you know that $\cos(4\varphi) = \cos^2(2\varphi) - \sin^2(2\varphi)$ and how to use the double-angle formulas for sine and cosine on that? $\qquad$

Comment: you want to plot or get in terms of x,y

Comment: @MichaelHardy, in this case it does lighten the path for me. The main concern for me is how to operate when there is a multiplicator in a trigonometry function, f.e. $r = 10 \sin(3φ)$

Comment: @Boris, the end goal is to graph the function in Cartesian, however, one must convert it from polar to Cartesian in order to do so.

Comment: you can plot the polar coordinates by varying $\phi $ from 0 to pi

Comment: @OssLog : $$\begin{align} \sin(3\varphi) & = \sin(\varphi+2\varphi) \\ & = \sin\varphi \cos(2\varphi) + \cos\varphi \sin(2\varphi) \\ & = (\text{then use double-angle formulas, etc.})  \end{align}$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, ah, yes. What about this case: $ φ = \dfrac r {r-1}$, $r > 1$ ? How does one go about converting it? I tried converting it to the form of $ r = \dfrac φ {φ-1}$, but couldn't solve this any further

Comment: ok, All my comments above are hereby declared to be missing the point: I would graph $r=\cos(4\varphi)$ by plotting points, but not by plotting INDIVIDUAL points. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, do you mean you would approximate points without finding out the exact points in Cartesian system?

Answer (score 0):

- Use $x=r\cos\varphi=\cos 4\varphi\cos\varphi$ and similar for $y$
- Use $x=r\cos\varphi=r\cos\dfrac{r}{r-1}$ and similar for $y$.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the relation $\phi=\arctan\left(\dfrac yx\right)$. Simply substitute

1. $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\cos\left(4\arctan\left(\dfrac yx\right)\right)$,
2. $\arctan\left(\dfrac yx\right)=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}}.$

By trigonometric transformations, the first equation can be rewritten as a polynomial of a high degree in $x,y$, while the second has no simple form.

$$64x^{12}-144x^{10}+81x^8-x^6-32x^4y^5+54x^4y^4-12x^2y^6-3x^2y^4+y^8-y^6-16y^4x^6+192y^3x^6+352y^2x^8-108y^2x^6-3y^2x^4+256yx^{10}-288yx^8=0.$$

---

As plotting directly in Cartesian coordinates requires numerical root finding methods, it is much more advisable to use paramtric forms,

1. $x=r\cos(\phi)=\cos(4\phi)\cos(\phi),\\y=r\sin(\phi)=\cos(4\phi)\sin(\phi),$
2. $y=r\cos\left(\dfrac r{r-1}\right),\\x=r\sin\left(\dfrac r{r-1}\right).$